# Why this c++ code is not returning address of each character in the array?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the addresses of each character in the array as follows:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    cout<<&arr[0]<<endl;
    cout<<&arr[1]<<endl;
    cout<<&arr[2]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But the output I am getting is as follows:

```
abc0╒@
bc0╒@
c0╒@
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The output does not look like an address with hexadecimal digits, but just some random characters. Am I missing some concepts here? I want to get the address of each character in the array arr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `&arr[i]` is a `char*`.

The class of which `cout` is an instance has an overloaded `<<` operator for a `const char*`. It treats the pointer as the start of a NUL-terminated string, and outputs the data as text.

You are observing the effects of *undefined behaviour* as a NUL-terminator is not reached. If you had written

```
char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0};
```

then the program behaviour would be defined.

If you want to output addresses then use `cout << (const void*)&arr[0] << endl;` &c.

Comment: @Peter: Yes you're correct. Thank you, I've taken out the sloppiness. (Do please feel free to downvote answers for imprecision - it's not to be taken personally.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print out the address, you could cast them (from `char*`) to `void*` firstly.

```
cout<<static_cast<void*>(&arr[0])<<endl;
cout<<static_cast<void*>(&arr[1])<<endl;
cout<<static_cast<void*>(&arr[2])<<endl;
```

Otherwise, they will be considererd as [c-style string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte), and the content of the string is trying to be printed out. Since `arr` doesn't have the null terminator `'\0'` at last, the behavior is undefined here.